# Add line break between timestamps in log with regex

Tags: regex

I have some log data:

```
2017-12-03 01:35:58 [Notice] syslog: local  IP address 
2017-12-03 01:35:58 [Notice] syslog: remote IP address 
2017-12-03 01:35:58 [Notice] syslog: primary   DNS address 
2017-12-03 01:35:58 [Notice] syslog: secondary DNS address 
2017-12-03 01:35:59 [Warning] kernel: Link State: PVC_8_0 logistic interface up.
2017-12-03 01:35:59 [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: started, version 2.52 cachesize 150
2017-12-03 01:35:59 [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: compile time options: no-IPv6 GNU-getopt no-RTC no-DBus no-I18N no-DHCP no-TFTP
2017-12-03 01:35:59 [Warning] dnsmasq[10463]: ignoring nameserver 127.0.0.1 - local interface
2017-12-03 01:35:59 [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: using nameserver 87.216.1.66#53(via ppp80)
2017-12-03 01:35:59 [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: using nameserver 87.216.1.65#53(via ppp80)
2017-12-03 01:35:59 [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: read /etc/hosts - 6 addresses
2017-12-03 01:36:00 [Informational] dnsmasq[10532]: started, version 2.52 cachesize 150
2017-12-03 01:36:00 [Informational] dnsmasq[10532]: compile time options: no-IPv6 GNU-getopt no-RTC no-DBus no-I18N no-DHCP no-TFTP
2017-12-03 01:36:00 [Informational] dnsmasq[10532]: using nameserver 87.216.1.66#53(via ppp80)
2017-12-03 01:36:01 [Warning] kernel: ^M
2017-12-03 01:36:01 [Warning] kernel: Send DNS Query : domain=ntp2.jazztel.com qType=A dnsServer=87.216.1.65
2017-12-03 01:36:01 [Warning] kernel: domain: ntp2.jazztel.com , IP: 87.216.1.241
2017-12-03 01:36:01 [Warning] kernel: sntp server=ntp2.jazztel.com: 0x5 ntpServerIP=87.216.1.241
```

I want to add a line break every time the timestamp changes so it looks like this:

```
2017-12-03 01:35:58 [Notice] syslog: local  IP address 
2017-12-03 01:35:58 [Notice] syslog: remote IP address 
2017-12-03 01:35:58 [Notice] syslog: primary   DNS address 
2017-12-03 01:35:58 [Notice] syslog: secondary DNS address 

2017-12-03 01:35:59 [Warning] kernel: Link State: PVC_8_0 logistic interface up.
2017-12-03 01:35:59 [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: started, version 2.52 cachesize 150
2017-12-03 01:35:59 [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: compile time options: no-IPv6 GNU-getopt no-RTC no-DBus no-I18N no-DHCP no-TFTP
2017-12-03 01:35:59 [Warning] dnsmasq[10463]: ignoring nameserver 127.0.0.1 - local interface
2017-12-03 01:35:59 [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: using nameserver 87.216.1.66#53(via ppp80)
2017-12-03 01:35:59 [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: using nameserver 87.216.1.65#53(via ppp80)
2017-12-03 01:35:59 [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: read /etc/hosts - 6 addresses

2017-12-03 01:36:00 [Informational] dnsmasq[10532]: started, version 2.52 cachesize 150
2017-12-03 01:36:00 [Informational] dnsmasq[10532]: compile time options: no-IPv6 GNU-getopt no-RTC no-DBus no-I18N no-DHCP no-TFTP
2017-12-03 01:36:00 [Informational] dnsmasq[10532]: using nameserver 87.216.1.66#53(via ppp80)

2017-12-03 01:36:01 [Warning] kernel: ^M
2017-12-03 01:36:01 [Warning] kernel: Send DNS Query : domain=ntp2.jazztel.com qType=A dnsServer=87.216.1.65
2017-12-03 01:36:01 [Warning] kernel: domain: ntp2.jazztel.com , IP: 87.216.1.241
2017-12-03 01:36:01 [Warning] kernel: sntp server=ntp2.jazztel.com: 0x5 ntpServerIP=87.216.1.241
```

This works at https://regexr.com:

`s/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} ).*\n(?!\1)/$0\n/g`

But when I try it in Terminal (OSX) it doesn't do anything:

`curl -s http://192.168.1.1/cgi-bin/status_log2.cgi | grep 2017 | tail -n 30 | perl -pe 's/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} ).*\n(?!\1)/$0\n/g'`

I also tried `gsed` and `sed` to no avail.

(Bonus if there's a way to remove all the redundant timestamps completely!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put a line break before each new time:

```
awk '!a[$1,$2]++ && NR>1{print ""} 1'
```

**How it works:** In awk, `$1` and `$2` are the first fields, in this case the date and time.  `a[$1,$2]` is an associative array that counts how many times we have seen those two fields.  If we have seen this date and time before, `!a[$1,$2]` and we are not on the first line, `NR>1`, then we print a blank line for separation, `print ""`.  The final `1` is just shorthand for print-the-current-line.

#### Example

With your sample logs in the file `logfile`:

```
$ awk '!a[$1,$2]++ && NR>1{print ""} 1' logfile
2017-12-03 01:35:58 [Notice] syslog: local  IP address 
2017-12-03 01:35:58 [Notice] syslog: remote IP address 
2017-12-03 01:35:58 [Notice] syslog: primary   DNS address 
2017-12-03 01:35:58 [Notice] syslog: secondary DNS address 

2017-12-03 01:35:59 [Warning] kernel: Link State: PVC_8_0 logistic interface up.
2017-12-03 01:35:59 [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: started, version 2.52 cachesize 150
2017-12-03 01:35:59 [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: compile time options: no-IPv6 GNU-getopt no-RTC no-DBus no-I18N no-DHCP no-TFTP
2017-12-03 01:35:59 [Warning] dnsmasq[10463]: ignoring nameserver 127.0.0.1 - local interface
2017-12-03 01:35:59 [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: using nameserver 87.216.1.66#53(via ppp80)
2017-12-03 01:35:59 [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: using nameserver 87.216.1.65#53(via ppp80)
2017-12-03 01:35:59 [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: read /etc/hosts - 6 addresses

2017-12-03 01:36:00 [Informational] dnsmasq[10532]: started, version 2.52 cachesize 150
2017-12-03 01:36:00 [Informational] dnsmasq[10532]: compile time options: no-IPv6 GNU-getopt no-RTC no-DBus no-I18N no-DHCP no-TFTP
2017-12-03 01:36:00 [Informational] dnsmasq[10532]: using nameserver 87.216.1.66#53(via ppp80)

2017-12-03 01:36:01 [Warning] kernel: ^M
2017-12-03 01:36:01 [Warning] kernel: Send DNS Query : domain=ntp2.jazztel.com qType=A dnsServer=87.216.1.65
2017-12-03 01:36:01 [Warning] kernel: domain: ntp2.jazztel.com , IP: 87.216.1.241
2017-12-03 01:36:01 [Warning] kernel: sntp server=ntp2.jazztel.com: 0x5 ntpServerIP=87.216.1.241
```

### Removing duplicated timestamps

```
$ awk '{if(a[$1,$2]++){gsub(/./," ",$1); gsub(/./," ",$2)} else if (NR>1) print""} 1' logfile
2017-12-03 01:35:58 [Notice] syslog: local  IP address 
                    [Notice] syslog: remote IP address
                    [Notice] syslog: primary DNS address
                    [Notice] syslog: secondary DNS address

2017-12-03 01:35:59 [Warning] kernel: Link State: PVC_8_0 logistic interface up.
                    [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: started, version 2.52 cachesize 150
                    [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: compile time options: no-IPv6 GNU-getopt no-RTC no-DBus no-I18N no-DHCP no-TFTP
                    [Warning] dnsmasq[10463]: ignoring nameserver 127.0.0.1 - local interface
                    [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: using nameserver 87.216.1.66#53(via ppp80)
                    [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: using nameserver 87.216.1.65#53(via ppp80)
                    [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: read /etc/hosts - 6 addresses

2017-12-03 01:36:00 [Informational] dnsmasq[10532]: started, version 2.52 cachesize 150
                    [Informational] dnsmasq[10532]: compile time options: no-IPv6 GNU-getopt no-RTC no-DBus no-I18N no-DHCP no-TFTP
                    [Informational] dnsmasq[10532]: using nameserver 87.216.1.66#53(via ppp80)

2017-12-03 01:36:01 [Warning] kernel: ^M
                    [Warning] kernel: Send DNS Query : domain=ntp2.jazztel.com qType=A dnsServer=87.216.1.65
                    [Warning] kernel: domain: ntp2.jazztel.com , IP: 87.216.1.241
                    [Warning] kernel: sntp server=ntp2.jazztel.com: 0x5 ntpServerIP=87.216.1.241
```

In this case, if we have seen the date, `$1`, and time, `$2`, before, then we replace their contents with blanks, `gsub(/./," ",$1); gsub(/./," ",$2)`.  If not and if we are not on the first line, then we print a blank line for separation.

Comment: @Ze'ev I'm glad this worked for you.  If you are interested in learning more about awk, a tutorial that I like is [the Grymoire tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell Perl to load the whole thing at once, as it normally reads the input line by line. Use `-0777` for that.

Also, `$0` in Perl is the name of the script (`-e` for a one-liner). Capture the whole line and reference it as `$1`, use `\2` for the date:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/((\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} ).*\n)(?!\2)/$1\n/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to post a (GNU)sed solution.

```
sed -nr 'h;s/^([^[]+) \[.*/\1/;x;p;:a;g;N;s/^([^\n]+)\n\1(.*)/\1\2/;Tb;:c;s/[0-9:-]([0-9 :-]+\[)/ \1/;tc;p;ba;:b;s/^[^\n]+//;P;D' logfile
2017-12-03 01:35:58 [Notice] syslog: local  IP address                                                                                      
                    [Notice] syslog: remote IP address                                                                                      
                    [Notice] syslog: primary   DNS address                                                                                  
                    [Notice] syslog: secondary DNS address                                                                                  

2017-12-03 01:35:59 [Warning] kernel: Link State: PVC_8_0 logistic interface up.                                                            
                    [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: started, version 2.52 cachesize 150                                                     
                    [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: compile time options: no-IPv6 GNU-getopt no-RTC no-DBus no-I18N no-DHCP no-TFTP         
                    [Warning] dnsmasq[10463]: ignoring nameserver 127.0.0.1 - local interface                                               
                    [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: using nameserver 87.216.1.66#53(via ppp80)                                              
                    [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: using nameserver 87.216.1.65#53(via ppp80)                                              
                    [Informational] dnsmasq[10463]: read /etc/hosts - 6 addresses                                                           

2017-12-03 01:36:00 [Informational] dnsmasq[10532]: started, version 2.52 cachesize 150                                                     
                    [Informational] dnsmasq[10532]: compile time options: no-IPv6 GNU-getopt no-RTC no-DBus no-I18N no-DHCP no-TFTP         
                    [Informational] dnsmasq[10532]: using nameserver 87.216.1.66#53(via ppp80)                                              

2017-12-03 01:36:01 [Warning] kernel: ^M                                                                                                    
                    [Warning] kernel: Send DNS Query : domain=ntp2.jazztel.com qType=A dnsServer=87.216.1.65
                    [Warning] kernel: domain: ntp2.jazztel.com , IP: 87.216.1.241
                    [Warning] kernel: sntp server=ntp2.jazztel.com: 0x5 ntpServerIP=87.216.1.241
```